# Jmeter throwing errors when saving graph

Tags: jmeter

My end goal is to save/output the graph in my local folder after the tests complete. I am saving the summary report as a CSV file in the folder and reading it jp@gc graph generator. I want to save timeOverTime graph locally. I can see in Jmeter the graph being generated, and its getting

I am getting two errors

1. CSV file is empty, I can see the data getting saved in it.
2. g.ObjectTableModel: Header count=13 but writeFunctor count=11

I am adding the screenshots below of how I am saving the files.

[image: Graph generator]
Graph generator

[image: Summary report being saved]
Summary report being saved

[image: Error showing]
Error showing

[image: CSV file being generated]
CSV file being generated

Answer (score 0):

It is not "throwing" and this is not an "error", see [log4j Logging Levels](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_levels.htm) for all possible message statuses.

If you look at [JMeter Source code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/reporters/ResultCollector.java#L376) you will see that this warning is being printed to log file when the results file doesn't contain any lines (is empty), most probably your `fleet_date_ranges.csv` is present but it doesn't contain any lines.

If you don't want to see these `WARN` messages in the future you can change this line of *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
<Configuration status="WARN" packages="org.apache.jmeter.gui.logging">
```

to this:

```
<Configuration status="INFO" packages="org.apache.jmeter.gui.logging">
```

More information:

- [Log4j Configuration Syntax](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#ConfigurationSyntax)
- [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging)